# Field value not displaying on mail

Tags: email-template

I have created one email template as below-

> Hello,
>
> One query has been asked for the Project
>   `{!Queries_on_Project__c.Project__c}` by.
>
> Question :  `{!Queries_on_Project__c.Ask_a_question__c}`
>
> To reply this question click on `{!Queries_on_Project__c.Link}`
>
> Thank you.

When the mail sends to reciepient, fields are displaying as blank value.

Comment: How do you send this email?

Comment: which type of email template is this?

Comment: i have written a trigger on object to send a mail. This is a plain text email template.

Comment: Try using VF email template

Comment: Post your trigger where you are fetching this template.are you updating the template with new trigger values before sending the mail?

Comment: Are you setting objectId using setTargetObjectId ? How you are setting values into the merge fields of email template? Please post your code here so that we can help you better!